# Create a GUI with clickable buttons

Tags: autohotkey

I have created the following code that triggers a pop screen with some buttons

```
#m::
 Gui, Show, w200 h200, Window title
 Gui, Add, Button, default, 1
 Gui, Add, Button, default, 2
 Gui, Add, Button, default, 2
Return
```

I would like to add now however what I should do to add a function for these buttons. I would like to go to particular websites if I enter then number. So for example to http>//www,nu.nl if I press 1.

Any advice on how I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#UseHook

Gui, +AlwaysOnTop +Resize
Gui, add, Button, x5 y10 w250 h20 g1, 1 --> autohotkey questions - Stack Overflow 
Gui, add, Button, x5 y30 w250 h20 g2, 2 --> windows-10 questions - Stack Overflow
Gui, add, Button, x5 y50 w250 h20 g3, 3 --> command-line questions - Stack Overflow
return
 
#m:: Gui, show, x0 y0 w280 h200 NoActivate, Websites


1:: Run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey
2:: Run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10
3:: Run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Comment: Then mark it as the answer to your question!